# Добавление дополнительного товара в корзину при выборе определенного

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Добрый день, подскажите , пожалуйста, есть ли плагин или сниппкт для реализации следующего: есть определенная группа товаров акционных, которые продаются при условии что будет куплено еще некоторое количество другого това, пример, куллер для питьевой воды со скидкой в 15% можно купить при одновременном заказе 4 бутылей воды. Или диспенсер с 10% скидкой можно купить при условии покупки 2 бутылей воды.
Хотелось бы для тех кто выбирает эту акцию чтобы в корзину уже было добавлено то или иное количество бутылей. Так как куллеров и диспенсеров моделей много и они само собой продаются без скидок реализовать это группировкой товаров не получается, подходящего плагина не нашел даже в платных

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пока получилось реализовать только посредством добавления **?add-to-cart=538&quantity=2** к кнопке, которая перебрасывает на страницу с категорией акционных товаров. 538 - это id товара, который я хочу чтобы был добавлен в корзину, а 2 - это количество его в корзине. Код кнопки следующий:
`<a class="bttn adding_to_cart bttn_akciya_for_dispencer" href="/product-category/specialnye-ceny/dispensery-s-15-skidkoj/?add-to-cart=538&quantity=2" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="538" data-product_sku="" data-quantity="2">Выбрать диспенсер</a>`